# SIEM система KUMA от Каперского

Tags: linux, kaspersky

В общем, установил я KUMA на виртуальную машину, активировал всё. Захожу в веб-интерфейс и у меня ничего нет там,а мне нужно настроить хотя бы пару источников, чтобы отсмотреть их..
Помогите пожалуйста, мне нужен простой алгоритм как подключить простые сервисы и источники, без очень замудренных текстовых инструкций от самого Касперского.